# How to call my created method on my getProjectLists in order to remove HTML tags from String

Tags: html, grails, methods, groovy, tags

This is my getProjectLists action

```
  def getProjectLists() {
      def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
      def kups = ([['name':'<b>Sample 1</b>'.removeHthml()],
      ['name':'<b>Sample 2</b>']])
  render kups as JSON  
 }
```

And this is my class and method

```
class HtmlTagRemove {
    static String removeHthml(String inputStr) {
      return inputStr.replaceAll("<.*?>","")
    }
}
```

This the error I encountered

```
No signature of method: java.lang.String.removeHtml() is applicable for argument types: () value: []
```

**FOLLOW-UP**
(Even though the original question was answered, my follow up question is as follows)

What can I do to make my method callable from a String like: `'<b>Sample 1</b>'.removeHtml()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the follow-up question:

You could extend the String class. [Documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_extending_interfaces)

```
​String.metaClass.removeHtml {    
    delegate.replaceAll("<.*?>","")
}

'<b>Sample 1</b>'.removeHtml()
```

I would use a library like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org) to remove html from a string:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html)
return doc.text())
```

Comment: Hi Sascha, thanks for the answer but how can i implement the String.metaClass.removeHtml{} in my UserController.groovy? I'm so sorry i'm new on groovy.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.8 version of grails

Comment: You could put that (`String.metaClass.removeHtml…`) into the BootStrap.groovy init method

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that they are in the same package (otherwise you need to import `HtmlTagRemove` or quality it with a full package name) you can do this:

`def kups = ([['name':HtmlTagRemove.removeHthml('<b>Sample 1</b>')],
      ['name':'<b>Sample 2</b>']])`

The reason being is that `removeHtml` is a static method.

Comment: Hi joshua thanks for the answer, but is there a way where  i can call the method in this form .removeHtml()

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer to the original question. My answer is based on  @Kim Remonte's question in the comment above.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken agreed, but I think KimRemonte is new to SO ;) Maybe I should edit his question with his follow up from the comment?

Comment: @Joshua Moore OK from my side.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken Done.